# Cold water from both taps only in kitchen

Tags: plumbing

The faucet in our kitchen is running cold from both hot and cold valves. The faucet is double handle.
The hot and cold water in the other areas of the house are running normally both hot and cold . We can't figure it out.....it occured seemingly overnight.

Comment: the heater probably failed.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Then why would hot water be working in other areas of the house?

Comment: @Zaz dedicated small-tank/tankless heater for the kitchen that broke, while the large boiler for the bathroom still works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dedicated heater for the kitchen, then the obvious conclusion is that it broke. *Thanks to @ratchet freak for pointing this out.*

I had a similar problem without a dedicated heater where the hot tap in the kitchen was slightly warmer than the cold one. I turned the boiler to a higher setting and now it works fine. I have no idea why the rest of the hot water in the house worked fine.